# Get value from MySQL database and populate dropdown box

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, fetch, dropdown

I hope someone can help me figure this out as I'm new to PHP and MySQL. But basically, what I'm trying to do is to pull the data from the database and populate the dropdown box and textbox, and so I can update the value in the textbox.

This is the table structure:

```
id | hf_name | hf_price
------------------------
AI | test 1  | 123
AI | test 2  | 123
```

So let's say I wanna update "test 1" price, I would select "test 1" in the dropdown selection and update the price in the textbook.

This are my code:

```
<form class='data_form' action='data/food_update.inc.php' method='post'>
    <select>
        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):; ?>
            <option><?php echo $row[1];?></option>
        <?php endwhile;?>
    </select>
    <input type='number' name='hf_price' placeholder='$'>
    <button type='submit'>UPDATE</button>
</form>
```

Include:

```
<?php

    //CONNECTION TO MySQL   
    include '../dbh.php';

    //VARIABLES
    $hf_name = $_POST['hf_name'];
    $hf_price = $_POST['hf_price'];
    $by_user = $_SESSION['Fname'];
    $up_date = date('Y-m-d'); 

        $sql = "SELECT hf_name FROM hotfoods";
        $result = mysql_query($conn, $sql);

?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: In your `include` you have `mysql_query()` and in your actual code you have `mysqli_fetch_array()`. I'm pretty sure they can't be used together, perhaps you had a typo and meant `mysql_fetch_array()` without the **i**. But as Jens says, you should stop using mysql_* functions and switch over to something like PDO or mysqli.

Comment: Also try using `<?php echo $row['hf_name'];?>` PHP arrays start at 0, you're attempting to get the result from index 1 which I would imagine wouldn't exist from your SQL query.

Comment: I donna ansa questions that contain the word 'wanna'. Jus' sayin'.

Comment: Yes thank you for pointing that one out. It was a typo, but even if I use mysqli, it still gives me an empty dropdown box.

Comment: Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the option to

```
<option value="<?php echo $row[2];?>"><?php echo $row[1];?></option>
```

Where I'm assuming `$row[2]` variable contains the `hf_price` value.

Comment: I tried this one, but the dropdown is still empty. I'm not sure what I'm really missing here. 

the first column is the id, second is hf_name, third is hf_price.

Comment: How do you mean the dropdown is still empty?

Comment: Check if the code comes in the `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result){` loop.

Answer (score 0):

but for this you need to change your id datatype into int,

```
 $query = "select * from tablename";
   $result = mysqli_query();

     <select id="nameID" name="hf_name">
          <?php 
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result){
              ?>
          <option value='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'><?php echo $row['hf_name']; ?></option>
    <?php
     }
      ?>
   </select>
```

This will be fine when you fetch details but it does not update any value because for this you need to use Ajax or Jquery for update on Select, let me to try it.

Ajax

```
$("#nameID").onchange(function(){
    var id = $("#id").val();
    $.ajax(
        url: "update.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {'id'=id},                   
        success: function(){
               alert("ok");                                    
         });
});
```

Try this it might work.

Comment: in the webpage I'm working on, I would like to have a dropdown box populated by the name of the food (hf_name) and a text box (hf_price) populated by the price depending on the name of the food selected.

let's say I wanna update the price of a specific food, I would select the name of the food from the dropdown box, and change the price from the textbox. Hope this is clear? Thanks.

Comment: Update in database column?

Comment: yes. update the price (hf_price) in the database column.

Comment: I've updated the answer check and try it. but must change things according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
     $query = "select * from tablename";
       $result = mysqli_query($query);

         <select>
              <?php 
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result){
                  ?>
              <option value='<?php echo $row['hf_name']; ?>'><?php echo $row['hf_name']; ?></option>
        <?php
         }
          ?>
       </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign a name attribute value (in this case, hf_name) on select element so that that become available in `$_POST` array.

```
<form class='data_form' action='data/food_update.inc.php' method='post'>
    <select name="hf_name">
        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):; ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['hf_name']?>"><?php echo $row['hf_name'];?></option>
        <?php endwhile;?>
    </select>
    <input type='number' name='hf_price' placeholder='$'>
    <button type='submit'>UPDATE</button>
</form>
```

Now this is on which the form will be submitted. Where you can take user's submitted data through `$_POST` array.

```
<?php

    //CONNECTION TO MySQL   
    include '../dbh.php';

    //VARIABLES
    $hf_name = $_POST['hf_name'];
    $hf_price = $_POST['hf_price'];

    $query = sprintf("UPDATE hotfoods SET hf_price='%d' WHERE hf_name='%s'",
        mysql_real_escape_string($hf_price),
        mysql_real_escape_string($hf_name));

    $result = mysql_query($conn, $query);
    if ($result) {
        echo 'Price updated!';
    } else {
        echo 'Problem while updating price';
    }

?>
```